# Vb.Net instantiate a Property of a class that is an array of a different class

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, instantiation

This is for the purpose of Serializing and Deserializing an Xml object

```
<XmlRoot("orderadd")>
<Serializable()> _
Public Class clsSMsgRequestMessage
    <XmlElementAttribute()> Public Property ordertype() As String
    <XmlElementAttribute()> Public Property vehicleid() As String
    <XmlElementAttribute()> Public Property orderpriority() As String
    <XmlElementAttribute("orderpart")> Public Property orderpart() As RequestMessageOrderaddOrderpart()
    <XmlAttributeAttribute()> Public Property clientid() As String
    <XmlAttributeAttribute()> Public Property transactionid() As String
    <XmlAttributeAttribute()> Public Property numberoforderparts() As String

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class RequestMessageOrderaddOrderpart
    <XmlElementAttribute()> Public Property operation() As String
    <XmlElementAttribute()> Public Property location() As String
    <XmlElementAttribute()> Public Property loadtype() As String
    <XmlAttributeAttribute()> Public Property orderpartnumber() As String

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

End Class
```

This works correctly for deserializing, but now I am trying to create this object correctly so I can serialize it back to an XML object.

```
Dim anotherTest As clsSMsgRequestMessage = New clsSMsgRequestMessage()
Dim testOrderPart1 As New RequestMessageOrderaddOrderpart


anotherTest.clientid = "data"
anotherTest.orderpriority = "data"
anotherTest.ordertype = "data"
anotherTest.transactionid = "data"
anotherTest.vehicleid = "data"
anotherTest.numberoforderparts = "data"

testOrderPart1.loadtype = "data"
testOrderPart1.location = "data"
testOrderPart1.operation = "data"
testOrderPart1.orderpartnumber = "data"


anotherTest.orderpart(0) = testOrderPart1
```

The last line here doesn't work because anotherTest.orderpart(0) isn't instantiated yet. But I don't know how to instantiate it because

```
anotherTest.orderpart(0) = New RequestMessageOrderaddOrderPart
```

still comes back with a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
anotherTest.orderpart = New RequestMessageOrderaddOrderPart
```

comes back with "Value of type  cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of "

I think I'm on the right track with instantiating it by itself like I'm doing with 'testOrderPart1' but I don't know how to link that to my anotherTest.orderpart

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize your array property first:

```
anotherTest.orderpart = New RequestMessageOrderaddOrderPart(10) {}
```

`10` is array size.

After that you'll be able to set first array element:

```
anotherTest.orderpart(0) = New RequestMessageOrderaddOrderPart
```

**Update**

However, I think you should change your property declaration to become `List(Of RequestMessageOrderaddOrderPart)`. With a list you don't have to specify number of items:

```
anotherTest.orderpart = New List(Of RequestMessageOrderaddOrderPart)()
```

Adding items is really easy:

```
anotherTest.orderpart.Add(new RequestMessageOrderaddOrderPart())
```

And you're still able to get/modify items using indexers:

```
Dim firstItem = anotherTest.orderpart(0)
```

Of course, that item has to be inserted using `Add` method first.

`List(Of T)` will work fine with serialization as well.

Comment: oh cool thanks! Do I have to set it to a fixed size like that? basically the XML message will have a variable number of 'parts' coming back and I won't know. I suppose they'll never have more than 20 or so parts - would be okay to just initialize a huge array and then regularly not use most of them?

Comment: I highly suggest using a `List(Of RequestMessageOrderaddOrderpart)` instead of an array